SwiftUI Map has poor performance while dynamically changing frame size
I have a Map() coming from MapKit. The map should smoothly change its size between 300px and 600px when I press a button. I achieved the required functionality, but the map is very laggy while resizing (FPS drops down to 15-20). However, performance issue happens only on a real device (iphone 13), if I run the same code on a preview simulator in Xcode everything works smoothly.
Map()
    .frame(height: isMapExpanded ? 600 : 300)

Button("Expand map") {
    withAnimation {
        isMapExpanded.toggle()
    }  
}

I already have tried to use MapView instead of Map - same outcome.
Also, seems like internet has no mentions about such problem...

purely FWIW I have not found this problem (real phone).  somewhat related question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78632823
